# Replace [1-2] in to 1 in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to replace `[1-2]` with **1**, `[3-4]` with **3**, `[7-8]` with **7**, `[2]` with **2**, and so on.

For example, I would like to use the following strings:

```
db[1-2].abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
db[3-4].abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
db[1].abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
xyz-db[1-2].abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
```

and convert them to

```
db1.abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
db3.abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
db1.abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
xyz-db1.abc.xyz.pqr.abc.abc.com
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stack Overflow is here to answer specific questions, but not to write code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex like:

```
^(.*)\[([0-9]+).*?\](.*)$
```

and replace it with:

```
$1$2$3
```

Here's what the regex does:

> **^** matches the beginning of the string
>   **(.*)** matches any character any amount of times, and is also the first capture group
>   **\[** matches the character [ literally
>   **([0-9]+)** matches any number 1 or more times, and is also the second capture group
>   **.*?** matches any character any amount of times, but tries to find the smallest match
>   **\]** matches the character ] literally
>   **(.*)** matches any characters any amount of times
>   **$** matches the end of the string

By replacing it with `$1$2$3`, you are replacing it with the text in the first capture group, followed by the text in the second capture group, followed by the text in the third capture group.

[Here's a live preview](https://regex101.com/r/rG9fD1/3) on regex101.com

Comment: The `*` in the square brackets should be non-greedy (alternatively, you can replace the dot with `[^\]]`).

Comment: The `.*\]` should be lazy

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

def fixString(strToFix):
    groups = re.match("(.*)\[(\d*).*\](.*)", strToFix).groups()
    return "%s%s%s" % (groups[0], groups[1], groups[2])
```

Comment: Same as above. Either you use the lazy star, or you change the dot to "anything but a `]`".

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This is especially true of regexen, which are notorious for being opaque line noise to most. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)